# Can I make my chips crunchy again after they have gone soggy?

Tags: tortilla-chips

Sometimes I forget that bag of salsa chips open and with the summer weather they go soggy.  How do I get them crunchy again before the guacamole is all gone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick and dirty way of achieving this is to microwave them for a bit. Microwave oven powers vary, so try 10 seconds first and add time as necessary. You'll find the right time for the right amount to bring your chips to nearly what they were prior to sitting out.

Comment: This worked well. Microwaved and then waited a few minutes before saving in a Ziploc.

Answer (score 12):

Try spreading them out on a cookie sheet and baking them at low heat for 15 minutes or so.

Answer (score 2):

I warmed mine in an iron frying pan for about two minutes on each side.  They turned out nice and crunchy.

Answer (score 1):

pan fry them for a minute or too in an iron skillet

Answer (score 1):

I have dried chips by leaving them in open in the freezer.